# link m3u8 not work( #EXTM3U #EXT-X-) IN VLC or web player

Tags: streaming, media-player, m3u8, m3u, iptv

hello i have this link iptv :

https://webui.vhls.ru.com/cdnus2/premium8/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8

it does not work in the program vlc or in jwplayer web .

the code source of this link m3u8 is :

[image code source m3u8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pele4.png)

```html
#EXTM3U #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5 #EXT-X-VERSION:3 #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:27702 #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-16T01:24:12Z #EXTINF:4.004, 2022/09/16/01/24/12-04004.ts #EXTINF:4.004, 2022/09/16/01/24/16-04004.ts #EXTINF:2.302, 2022/09/16/01/24/22-02302.ts #EXTINF:2.002, 2022/09/16/01/24/24-02002.ts #EXTINF:2.002, 2022/09/16/01/24/26-02002.ts #EXTINF:2.002, 2022/09/16/01/24/28-02002.ts
```

is there a way for it to work in vlc or jwplayer web ?

this m3u8 link working on this link normally .

livetvon .click/mylive/stream-8.php

### Heading

Answer (score 0):

Add the referrer URL on VLC:

```
:http-referrer=(referrer url)
```